# Multiple Postgres Docker Services

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run multiple postgres services - one for airflow and one as a database to be filled on execution of an airflow DAG. Here are my current services in docker-compose.yml:

```
  aact:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: aact
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: aact
      POSTGRES_DB: aact
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - ./snapshotsCreate.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/snapshotsCreate.sql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - trial_explorer_db_network
    profiles:
      - airflow
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: airflow, aact
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
    profiles:
      - airflow
```

When I try to use

```
docker exec -it <aact service container id> psql -U aact
```

I get this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "aact" does not exist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try connecting to the container and from it connecting to postgre: `docker exec -it <aact service container id> bash` then try `psql -U aact`

Comment: Doing ```docker exec -it <aact service container id> bash``` then ```psql -U aact``` worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear. I will put it as answer for you since it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the docker container first and from there connect to your postgresql database.

First run:

```
docker exec -it <aact service container id> bash
```

Then, once in the container connect to your database with:

```
psql -U aact
```